# Testing what a String token holds

Tags: java

I am making a calculator and part of this program takes in user `String` input and tokenizes it (using my own implementation of a `Tokenizer` class). So now I have a bunch of `Token` objects and I would like to test each one of them to see if they hold numbers or operators.

Is there a way to test to see if they hold operators (ie. +, -, *, /, =, (, ), etc.) without using
`if (token.equals("+") || token.equals("-") || ...` and so on, for each operator? These `Token` objects are all of type `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're all single-character strings you can do:

```
if ("+-*/=()".indexOf(token) > -1) {

    // if you get into this block then token is one of the operators.

}
```

You could use an array to hold values that indicate the precedence of the corresponding token, too:

```
int precedence[] = { 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4 };  // I think this is correct

int index = "+-*/=()".indexOf(token); 
if (index > -1) {

    // if you get into this block then token is one of the operators.
    // and its relative precedence is precedence[index]

}
```

But since this all assumes that the operator is only one character, this is about as far as you can take this approach.

Comment: Sorry, tested it and it does work, but only - as posted - to single character strings. +1.

Comment: Yes, if the tokens are operators then they would be single character. This is brilliantly simple. Thanks! +1

Comment: And also, if I re-order the `if` statement and then do calculations depending on what index is returned, I should be able to (roughly) determine operator precedence as well...right?

Answer (score 1):

You also can use String contains for this.

```
 String operators = "+-*/=()";
String token ="+";

if(operators.contains(token)){

    System.out.println("here");
}
```